# How to get Drush to find my site files?

Tags: 7, drush

I am currently sucking at getting Drush working on my site.  I've been through the basic composer install process, and have Drush 7 installed and running.  It even basically works:

```
[root@linux2 my_site_root]# drush ev "return 1+2"
3
```

However, when I cd to the root of a site and try something involving Drupal, it fails:

```
[root@linux2 my_site_root]# drush  ev "return node_load(255)" 
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function node_load() in /root/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/commands/core/core.drush.inc(1123) : eval()'d code on line 1
Fatal error: Call to undefined function node_load() in /root/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/commands/core/core.drush.inc(1123) : eval()'d code on line 1
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                                    [error]
Error: Call to undefined function node_load() in /root/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/commands/core/core.drush.inc(1123)
: eval()'d code, line 1
```

This is probably something blinding obvious, but I'm just not seeing it.  Can somebody get me on track?  Thanks!

-- edit w. more info

A sample invocation, which fails the same way that the others do.  FWIW, Drush is finding and executing settings.php, as shown by the printing of $_SERVER (via a print statement in settings.php).  Also note that DOCUMENT_ROOT is empty.

```
[root@linux2 example]# drush @example -d  -r /var/www/html/example --uri=http://www.example.com pm-refresh
Starting Drush preflight. [0.01 sec, 4.12 MB]                                                                               [preflight]
Cache HIT cid: 7.0.0-commandfiles-0-81cc86c1995ab7206f383ec28ad43baf [0.01 sec, 4.21 MB]                                        [debug]
Loaded alias @example from file /root/.drush/aliases.drushrc.php [0.1 sec, 10.22 MB]                                          [notice]
Cache SET cid: 7.0.0-alias-path--77857992f9834a08af48a4f5d331b674 [0.1 sec, 10.22 MB]                                           [debug]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.11 sec, 10.23 MB]                                                                                  [bootstrap]
Bootstrap to phase 6. [0.11 sec, 10.23 MB]                                                                                  [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_root() [0.12 sec, 10.82 MB]                                                        [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal 7.39 root directory at /var/www/html/example [0.12 sec, 10.82 MB]                                [notice]
Find command files for phase 1 (max=6) [0.13 sec, 8.51 MB]                                                                      [debug]
Cache HIT cid: 7.0.0-commandfiles-1-b4947ce06071f8161a156c8e4a27745b [0.13 sec, 8.52 MB]                                        [debug]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_site() [0.13 sec, 8.52 MB]                                                         [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal site www.example.com at sites/default [0.13 sec, 8.52 MB]                                            [notice]
Find command files for phase 2 (max=6) [0.13 sec, 8.52 MB]                                                                      [debug]
Cache HIT cid: 7.0.0-commandfiles-2-f17fc6bdab2f74278df75194ca483893 [0.13 sec, 8.53 MB]                                        [debug]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_configuration() [0.13 sec, 8.52 MB]                                                [bootstrap]
Just for fun, dump out _SERVER from inside settings.php: 
Array
(
    [HOSTNAME] => linux2.example.com
    [SHELL] => /bin/bash
    [TERM] => xterm-color
    [HISTSIZE] => 1000
    [SSH_CLIENT] => 192.168.0.6 53333 2995
    [QTDIR] => /usr/lib64/qt-3.3
    [QTINC] => /usr/lib64/qt-3.3/include
    [SSH_TTY] => /dev/pts/1
    [USER] => root
    [LS_COLORS] => rs=0:di=38;5;27:ln=38;5;51:mh=44;38;5;15:pi=40;38;5;11:so=38;5;13:do=38;5;5:bd=48;5;232;38;5;11:cd=48;5;232;38;5;3:or=48;5;232;38;5;9:mi=05;48;5;232;38;5;15:su=48;5;196;38;5;15:sg=48;5;11;38;5;16:ca=48;5;196;38;5;226:tw=48;5;10;38;5;16:ow=48;5;10;38;5;21:st=48;5;21;38;5;15:ex=38;5;34:*.tar=38;5;9:*.tgz=38;5;9:*.arj=38;5;9:*.taz=38;5;9:*.lzh=38;5;9:*.lzma=38;5;9:*.tlz=38;5;9:*.txz=38;5;9:*.zip=38;5;9:*.z=38;5;9:*.Z=38;5;9:*.dz=38;5;9:*.gz=38;5;9:*.lz=38;5;9:*.xz=38;5;9:*.bz2=38;5;9:*.tbz=38;5;9:*.tbz2=38;5;9:*.bz=38;5;9:*.tz=38;5;9:*.deb=38;5;9:*.rpm=38;5;9:*.jar=38;5;9:*.rar=38;5;9:*.ace=38;5;9:*.zoo=38;5;9:*.cpio=38;5;9:*.7z=38;5;9:*.rz=38;5;9:*.jpg=38;5;13:*.jpeg=38;5;13:*.gif=38;5;13:*.bmp=38;5;13:*.pbm=38;5;13:*.pgm=38;5;13:*.ppm=38;5;13:*.tga=38;5;13:*.xbm=38;5;13:*.xpm=38;5;13:*.tif=38;5;13:*.tiff=38;5;13:*.png=38;5;13:*.svg=38;5;13:*.svgz=38;5;13:*.mng=38;5;13:*.pcx=38;5;13:*.mov=38;5;13:*.mpg=38;5;13:*.mpeg=38;5;13:*.m2v=38;5;13:*.mkv=38;5;13:*.ogm=38;5;13:*.mp4=38;5;13:*.m4v=38;5;13:*.mp4v=38;5;13:*.vob=38;5;13:*.qt=38;5;13:*.nuv=38;5;13:*.wmv=38;5;13:*.asf=38;5;13:*.rm=38;5;13:*.rmvb=38;5;13:*.flc=38;5;13:*.avi=38;5;13:*.fli=38;5;13:*.flv=38;5;13:*.gl=38;5;13:*.dl=38;5;13:*.xcf=38;5;13:*.xwd=38;5;13:*.yuv=38;5;13:*.cgm=38;5;13:*.emf=38;5;13:*.axv=38;5;13:*.anx=38;5;13:*.ogv=38;5;13:*.ogx=38;5;13:*.aac=38;5;45:*.au=38;5;45:*.flac=38;5;45:*.mid=38;5;45:*.midi=38;5;45:*.mka=38;5;45:*.mp3=38;5;45:*.mpc=38;5;45:*.ogg=38;5;45:*.ra=38;5;45:*.wav=38;5;45:*.axa=38;5;45:*.oga=38;5;45:*.spx=38;5;45:*.xspf=38;5;45:
    [COLUMNS] => 135
    [PATH] => /root/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
    [MAIL] => /var/spool/mail/root
    [PWD] => /var/www/html/example
    [EDITOR] => emacs
    [LANG] => en_US.UTF-8
    [KDE_IS_PRELINKED] => 1
    [KDEDIRS] => /usr
    [HISTCONTROL] => ignoredups
    [SSH_ASKPASS] => /usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass
    [HOME] => /root
    [SHLVL] => 1
    [LOGNAME] => root
    [CVS_RSH] => ssh
    [QTLIB] => /usr/lib64/qt-3.3/lib
    [SSH_CONNECTION] => 192.168.0.6 53333 70.91.205.178 2995
    [LESSOPEN] => ||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
    [G_BROKEN_FILENAMES] => 1
    [PHP_SELF] => /index.php
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/html/example/index.php
    [PATH_TRANSLATED] => /root/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => 
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1444344277
    [argv] => Array
        (
            [0] => /root/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php
            [1] => --php=/usr/bin/php
            [2] => --php-options= -d magic_quotes_gpc=Off -d magic_quotes_runtime=Off -d magic_quotes_sybase=Off
            [3] => @example
            [4] => -d
            [5] => -r
            [6] => /var/www/html/example
            [7] => --uri=http://www.example.com
            [8] => pm-refresh
        )

    [argc] => 9
    [HTTP_HOST] => www.example.com
    [SERVER_PORT] => 
    [REQUEST_URI] => /
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => 
    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => 
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => 
    [HTTP_REFERER] => 
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.0
)
Find command files for phase 3 (max=6) [0.14 sec, 9.43 MB]                                                                      [debug]
Bootstrap to phase 5. [0.14 sec, 9.58 MB]                                                                                   [bootstrap]
Command pm-refresh needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal      [error]
environment to run this command. [0.15 sec, 9.59 MB]
The drush command 'pm-refresh' could not be executed. [0.15 sec, 9.59 MB]                                                   [error]
Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.                                                                [error]
Hint: This may occur when Drush is trying to:
 * bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a configured database. In this case you can select another
site with a working database setup by specifying the URI to use with the --uri parameter on the command line. See `drush
topic docs-aliases` for details.
 * connect the database through a socket. The socket file may be wrong or the php-cli may have no access to it in a jailed
shell. See http://drupal.org/node/1428638 for details.

Drush was attempting to connect to: 
 Drupal version         :  7.39                                         
 Site URI               :  http://www.example.com                
 Database driver        :  mysql                                        
 Database hostname      :  127.0.0.1                                    
 Database port          :  3306                                         
 Database username      :  examplead                                   
 Database name          :  exampledb                               
 PHP executable         :  /usr/bin/php                                 
 PHP configuration      :  /etc/php.ini                                 
 PHP OS                 :  Linux                                        
 Drush script           :  /root/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php 
 Drush version          :  7.0.0                                        
 Drush temp directory   :  /tmp                                         
 Drush configuration    :                                               
 Drush alias files      :  /root/.drush/aliases.drushrc.php             
 Drupal root            :  /var/www/html/example             
 Site path              :  sites/default                                

 [0.2 sec, 12.25 MB]
[root@linux2 example]#
```

Hope that helps -- thanks!

---

edit #2: it looks like my problem is that Drupal is not getting properly bootstrapped when getting launched through Drush.  I've added the following code to settings.php after the database properties are set up:

```
if (!function_exists('user_load')) {
    drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
}
```

and things seem to work in both web-based invocation and through Drush.  (user_load() was an arbitrary choice, but it seems to work.)

*WHY* this is the case, is, of course, a complete mystery to me.  Any insights out there?

---

edit #3: Further testing showed some conflicts between the solution in edit #2 and Ajax calls.  The following is working better:

```
if (!$_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']) {
    drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
}
```

[Yes, I'm obviously blindly hacking here.  More principled solutions would *definitely* be appreciated.]

Comment: What does `drush status` say?  Is your settings.php file in a folder named 'default'?  Try adding --uri=http://example.com, or run drush from the directory that contains settings.php.

Comment: Yes, settings is in sites/default; running from there still loses, as does adding a --uri arg.  status is too long to fit here, but everything looks right except perhaps for "Drush configuration" being blank and "Site path" being 'sites/default' (which is probably right, actually).  Does that help at all?

Comment: If everything looks right, maybe it is working. :) Maybe you could edit your question to include the exact output shown from `drush status`.